# PHP: Handle memory & code low memory usage

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

Yes I am having an issue with PHP memory. My host offer max. to use 64M memory limit, and somehow when i upload+crop functions exceeds this memory, and im receiving an error(not always though, depends on image size)

When I upload an image with around 1 mb or lower, it uploads, and you can crop and save it.

But when i upload an image with around 2 mb or higher (my limit on the uploadfunction is 6mb), it uploads, and then when you crop the image and want to save it i get "out of memory error."

I tried to imagedestroy() after any function in gd, i don't use anymore, but this didn't affect it. Although im only using GDfunctions in the case crop

So is there anything that i can free my memory off in the case upload?

Or maybe in general how to free the php memory usage?

Here's my script:

```
switch($action) {

    case 'upload':


    $userid = $USER;
    $user = getUserInfo($userid);
    $lasttime = $user['showURP']["photo_lasttime"];

    $upload_name = "file";
    $max_file_size_in_bytes = 8388608;
    $extension_whitelist = array("jpg", "gif", "png", "jpeg");

    /* checking extensions */
    $path_info = pathinfo($_FILES[$upload_name]['name']);
    $file_extension = $path_info["extension"];
    $is_valid_extension = false;
    foreach ($extension_whitelist as $extension) {
        if (strcasecmp($file_extension, $extension) == 0) {
            $is_valid_extension = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$is_valid_extension) {
        echo "{";
        echo        "error: 'Filtype not allowed!'\n";
        echo "}";
        exit(0);
    }
    /* checking filetype*/
switch(exif_imagetype($_FILES[$upload_name]['tmp_name'])) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        break;
    default:
        echo "{";
        echo        "error: 'This is no real image!'\n";
        echo "}";
        exit(0);
}

    /* file size check */
    $file_size = @filesize($_FILES[$upload_name]["tmp_name"]);
    if (!$file_size || $file_size > $max_file_size_in_bytes) {
        echo "{";
        echo        "error: 'Filesize exceeds the limit: 6MB'\n";
        echo "}";
        exit(0);
    }




    if(isset($_FILES[$upload_name]))
        if ($_FILES[$upload_name]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
            } else  {
                $userfile = stripslashes($_FILES[$upload_name]['name']);
                $file_size = $_FILES[$upload_name]['size'];
                $file_temp = $_FILES[$upload_name]['tmp_name'];
                $file_type = $_FILES[$upload_name]["type"];
                $file_err = $_FILES[$upload_name]['error'];
                $file_name = $userfile;

                if(move_uploaded_file($file_temp, "images/profilePhoto/".$file_name)) {
                    echo "{";
                    echo        "msg: '".$file_name."'";
                    echo "}";
                }
            }
    break;

    case 'crop':
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')   {


        $jpeg_quality = 90;

        $src = "images/profilePhoto/".$_POST['fname'];
        $ext= pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


    if($ext == "jpg" OR $ext == "jpeg" OR $ext == "JPG"){
        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src); // <-- im getting out of memory error on this line

    }elseif($ext == "png" OR $ext == "PNG"){
        $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
    }elseif($ext == "gif" OR $ext == "GIF"){
        $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($src);
    }

        if($_POST['fixed'] == 0) {
           $targ_w = $_POST['w'];
           $targ_h = $_POST['h'];
        }
        else {
            $targ_h = $_POST['sizeh']; 
            $targ_w = $_POST['sizew']; 
        }

        $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

        imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
        $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);
        imagedestroy($img_r); // free memory

    $path_thumbs = "images/profilePhoto/thumbs";
        $filename = $USER . ".jpg";
        $thumb_path = $path_thumbs . '/' . $filename;

        imagejpeg($dst_r,$thumb_path,$jpeg_quality);
        imagedestroy($dst_r); // free memory

        echo json_encode(array(
            'filename'=>$thumb_path
        ));
        unlink($src);       


    }   
    break;
}
```

My host is only supporting GD lib for cropping images, so imagemagick cant be used.

And as i mentioned previously, my host has a memory_limit on 64M, that cant be set

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you are going to be constrained by your memory limit. The GD library looks like it has horrid memory management. I just tried loading an image with the dimensions of 3951x2520 & my scripts memory usage went from 512KB before load to about 50MB after load(PHP 5.3.3, Windows 7 Home x64). The actual image should only be taking up about 28.49MB of memory, so why is GD taking almost double this amount? I have no idea.

**Edit**: Actually it looks like the reason is because GD stores the image in it's internal GD2 format which is not memory efficient.

**Edit2**: It appears GD2 format actually is only bloated by about 67% over an actual truecolor bitmap. Surprisingly the original GD format takes a smaller footprint than the original image itself or GD2. This I believe is due to dithering, which is noticeable on the output. The only way I can see to get a file loaded into original GD format is to first load it using it's image function(e.g. imagecreatefromjpeg) and then save it using `imagegd` (not `imagegd2`) then reload it back in with `imagecreatefromgd`. This is not very efficient and dithering definitely occurs.

**Final Edit**:

This I feel is a better function than the one I had earlier below. You give it the filename of your file along with the target height & width & it will check available memory and return true or false if you have enough to perform the resize. If you would prefer to just know approx how much memory is required then you can pass true as the $returnRequiredMem parameter.

```
function checkMemAvailbleForResize($filename, $targetX, $targetY,$returnRequiredMem = false, $gdBloat = 1.68) {
    $maxMem = ((int) ini_get('memory_limit') * 1024) * 1024;
    $imageSizeInfo = getimagesize($filename);
    $srcGDBytes = ceil((($imageSizeInfo[0] * $imageSizeInfo[1]) * 3) * $gdBloat);
    $targetGDBytes = ceil((($targetX * $targetY) * 3) * $gdBloat);
    $totalMemRequired = $srcGDBytes + $targetGDBytes + memory_get_usage();
    if ($returnRequiredMem) return $srcGDBytes + $targetGDBytes;
    if ($totalMemRequired > $maxMem) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Examples:

```
if (!checkMemAvailableForResize('path/to/file.jpg', 640,480)) die('Cannot resize!');
```

or:

```
$totalBytesNeeded = checkMemAvailableForResize('path/to/file.jpg',640,480,true);
```

Additionally you can adjust the $gdBloat parameter in case 68% is too little or too much overhead:

```
checkMemAvailableForResize('path/to/file.jpg',640,480,false, 1.69);
```

Comment: Hello. I have tested your script and successfully I am getting this error. I would like to know how you have set the dimensions limit?(how many height px and width px). Thank you

Comment: / how big can the image be? 1024px * 1024px ?

Comment: Well it's better to think in total pixels rather than actual dimensions. Example: 512x2048 equals 1048576 pixels, but so does 1024x1024. You could set a hard limit if you want of 1024x1024 and that will probably put you right at your limit. This script is suppose to be more flexible and calculate up to your memory limit better instead of imposing a hard limit. The first line controls how much memory a single image is allowed to take, you can change 32 to 24 or 48 and that will reduce or raise the amount of MB of ram the image is allowed to take.

Comment: It's because i would like to inform the user of how big the image could be. So i just inform them by max. 1024x1024 ?

Comment: You have to take into account A) how much memory your script is already using B) how much memory the uncompressed image is going to take & C) how much memory the uncompressed resampled image is going to take. My calculations suggest that you could probably go up to 2500x2500 as max resolution if your script takes less than 4MB on it's own and you are resizing to dimensions smaller than the original.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that while GD is manipulating an image, it's not stored in a compressed format. Thus, the amount of memory GD will need to work with the image is directly proportional to its size (width x height), whereas the image you're uploading is probably compressed, and thus may be much smaller on your own disk.

For instance, you might be uploading a 1MB file, but that file is actually 1024x1024 pixels and thus would take something like ~4MB of memory for GD to load - or if it were even larger (say 2048x2048) it would be more like 16MB of memory, etc.

Comment: Hi. Thank you, made me understand! But how can I solve this and lower the usage?

Comment: iam sure you have tried "ini_set(“memory_limit”,”1024M”); ? ;-)

Comment: Yes I have, I can't change it as my max is 64M

Answer (score 0):

Filesize doesnt matter on jpeg, because the stuff is compressed. If you work with this image, it is stored as bitmap in memory, and i think thats your Problem.

You could try ImageMagick because it does not need as much memory as gd!

[ImageMagick on php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/book.imagick.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should resize the image on client browser instead on server.
This is made with html5 canvas element. You can write your own function or use a plugin. There is a good jquery plugin to do this.

[Blueimp jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)